# displaying xml tag attributes with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to display an XML tag attribute via xslt but am having trouble figuring it out.

My xml file looks similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="results.xsl"?>
<search command="grep -n -i -I htm C:\firebreath\*">
<match number="1">
    <filename>C:\firebreath\CMakeLists.txt  </filename>
    <linenum>10 </linenum>
    <matchstring>#            http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html</matchstring>
</match>
</search>
```

And my XSLT file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>grep matches </h2>
<table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th>filename</th>
    <th>line number</th>
    <th>match string</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="search/match">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="filename"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="linenum"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="matchstring"/></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to display the command portion of the search tag before I begin to parse through the rest. Is there any way do to that? If so, how? A search didn't turn up anything particularly relevant...

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution. :)

Answer (score 4):

> I want to display the command portion
>   of the search tag before I begin to
>   parse through the rest.

**Read about the [`<xsl:value-of>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#value-of) XSLT instruction**.

And use:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="/search/@command"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I guess my problem had to deal with chrome, as it doesn't want to display attributes at all.

Comment: @user483281: that shouldn't matter, as long as you're not outputting the value of @command as an attribute. If you use `<xsl:value-of >`, you're outputting it as a string. I have not heard of Chrome not wanting to display attributes btw... do you mean Google Chrome or Mozilla chrome?